# HTML/CSS - Automatically adjust size of element for different screen size(s)

Tags: html, css

I'm brushing up my HTML/CSS skills and trying to build a website  where elements adjust automatically to different screen sizes; as an example, for the `header` I'm using the following code:

```
#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border:thin solid black;
}​
```

With the header im hoping to keep the element centered and adjust to the size of different screens, however my code above is flawed because

1. It is not centered
2. If I give it a width of 500px, i assume it will stay a fixed 500px and not adjust to different resolutions...

Here is an image of what it looks like, notice the element is not centered.
[image]

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: no need to use aabsolute positioning (*unless you need it for other reasons*). Just set left/right margins to `auto`  for the centering and set the width to be percentage based like `width:60%`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your `width` using relative percentage, such as `50%`, the actual width will be 50% of the parent width. To center the absolute header, you can set its `left` and `right` to `0` and `margin:0 auto`:

```
#header{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;    
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border:thin solid black;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ8wA/11/)

Answer (score 0):

**used to this**

```
#header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    border:thin solid black;
}​
```

Comment: Thank you, please tell me in the above example if I have 'width:500px' is that a fixed width? What do I do to let the width and size adjust? Should I assign it a percentage?

Comment: if you take 400 px width than define margin-left:200px; -------- Define any width of your container than define half margin-left in -px.

Answer (score 0):

when centering a div with top/left values, it is correct to give it 50% but you have to remember to subtract with margins half his height/width too.
for the width you can use `max-width` instead, this means that the div will be 500px wide if there's enough room, otherwise it will stretch as if it had a percentage width

here's my code

```
    #header{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px;
        margin-left: -250px;
        max-width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        border:thin solid black;
    }​
```